# Storing each digit from double to an array

Tags: arrays

I am a newbie at this and I am not sure on how to go about to store the digits of a double to an array. I have this double value: 0120.1098

I want it to be stored as something like this:

```
value[1] = 0
value[2] = 1
value[3] = 2
value[4] = 0
value[5] = 1
```

`

and so on...

How do I do it?

Comment: Whatfor do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to convert that value to a coordinate value using a formula but it is only possible if i can work with the individual digits...

Comment: How do you still know where the decimal was after this conversion? Or do you only need the digits >0?

Comment: If I can store the decimal point into the array as well it would be better. I just need to know the position of each digit and extract it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need to extract them, but as I don't know much more about your context, here you go. 
You could turn it into a `String`, split it on `.` and iterate. This way you get two int arrays. One for the digits before the decimal and on for the digits after de decimal.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 12323.213432;
    String asString = String.valueOf(d);
    String[] splitOnDecimal = asString.split("\\.");
    int[] upperBound = getIntArray(splitOnDecimal[0]);
    int[] lowerBound = getIntArray(splitOnDecimal[1]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(upperBound));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowerBound));
  }

  private static int[] getIntArray(String numberString) {
    int[] tmpArray = new int[numberString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++) {
        tmpArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberString.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    return tmpArray;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, this helped. But just one issue... if my double starts with a 0 (eg. 0123.456), 
upperBound[0] = 1

instead of 

upperBound[0] = 0

Is there a way to store the 0 into the array?

Comment: A double value never starts with a zero (exept a number between 1 and 0 of course). A String value might. If you use a String value like "034.34" with this function, you will have the 0 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will even show your zeroes:

```
String dbl = "0012300.00109800";
    int dblArraylength = dbl.length();

    char[] c = dbl.toCharArray();

    int dotId= dbl.indexOf(".");

    int a[] = new int[dblArraylength-1];

    for(int i=0; i<dotId; i++){
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString ((char)c[i]));
    }
    for(int i=dotId; i<a.length; i++){
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(Character.toString ((char)c[i+1]));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        System.out.println("a[" +i+ "] = " + a[i]); 
    }
```